# How do I export and import object from one repository to other?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, github, package.json

I have 2 github repositories written in typescript
one for initial data , next one project

what is the correct way to export and import it

here is code from initials repository

```js
import { listInitials} from "./src/list";
import { settingsInitials} from "./src/settings";
import { IInitials } from "./src/types";


const initials : IInitials= {
  listInitials,
  settingsInitials
}

export default initials
```

Their types

```js
export interface IListInitials extends Object {
    [key: string]: any;
 }

export interface ISettingsInitials extends Object {
    [key: string]: any;
}  

export interface IInitials{
  listInitials: IListInitials ,
  settingsInitials: ISettingsInitials 
}
```

package.json from main repositroy

```json
"dependencies": {
    "initials": "git+https://github.com/username/initials.git",
}
```

index.ts file where I try to import it

```js
import * as Initials from "initials";
console.log(Initials);
```

Error in console

```
./node_modules/initials/index.ts 6:15
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|
> const initials : IInitials= {
|   listInitials,
|   settingsInitials
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are try to run .ts files via node.js

Try to run

```
ts-node <index.ts> instead of node <index.ts>
```

Comment: the main project is react with typescript
I run it by npm run start

Comment: ok, it is not important here. Your build system can has setup which exclude compiling code on the fly under node_modules dir. That is right?

Answer (score 0):

Your React projects expects your `initials` module to be *built* (i.e. to provide JS files)

So you either need to run `tsc` on it to build it, and add js artifacts into git (the way it's done in NPM bundles which provide only js and d.ts),
or configure your React compiler to eat ts files in node_modules